# Why does the Path Tracer in Unreal Engine 5.3 not start/work but flicker when near my Meta Human LOD0?

Tags: 3d, unreal-engine5, rtx

The Path Tracer does not seem to work when I am near my Meat Human (LOD0, 1). It just flickers wildly and the red bar stays at 0%. When I scroll away or turn the viewport away from the Meta Human it works fine. The GPU is at 90-100% load, the frames drop to 5fps and the path tracing doesnt kick in.

I've tried to make the lights brigther. I've tried to restart the engine multiple times. I enabled ray tracing in the settings according to the tutorial by William Faucher. Tried to export but cant even get one frame be saved.

It looks like this: [this is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5thA.jpg) [working at LOD 3/4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6Q97.jpg)
(Config: Ryzen 7800 & RTX 4080. Studio Driver for the RTX. Unreal Engine 5.3.)

What am I missing here?